# Gitlab docker and external_url

Tags: docker, gitlab

Hello I installed latest gitlab using docker. I started the container with -p 10080:80 and 10022:22

I can browse gitlab and do what I need I can even git clone both http and ssh using ports 10080 and 10022 respectively.

In the front end though the urls don't show with the appropriate ports.

I changed the ssh_shell property. That works fine!

For whatever reason any attempt to modify the external_url property doesn't work! I put "http://myhost:10080" But when I restart the container it doesn't seem to want to start. I can't browse nothing simply commenting it out it works again.

So now the front end shows the correct ssh clone url, but not the http one.

Answer (score 5):

Ok figured it out thanks to this: [Gitlab docker not working if external_url is set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39351563/gitlab-docker-not-working-if-external-url-is-set)

Basically if you set external url with a port it also causes the nginx port to bind to that port. So when you start your docker containers you need to -p 10080:10080